# Can Operating system allocate a page of process to any free frame in memory?

Tags: operating-systems, paging, memory-allocation

Consider I have a user program of 6 pages and 4 byte page size. Now my memory has 300 frames out of which 10 frames are free for allocation. Can the OS allocate **page 1 of the given process to any of these 10 frames** or is there any specific algorithm to select a frame?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you can run any kind of OS in 300 frames of 4 bytes each.

Answer (score 1):

That's entirely up to the OS, and different OS's may have different strategies.  In principle, the OS could assign any frame it wants.

Comment: Thanks it was the solution i found as well.